# Laravel Excel::store (export) большой даты

Tags: laravel, excel, export

Экспортирую данные из базы через Laravel Excel export в базе более 200 000 элементов.
Но максимум экспортируется 90 000 далее уже сервер не справляется.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Http\Resources\Excel\ProductResource;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ProductsExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;


    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        set_time_limit(3000);
        
        $product = Product::with('images');
        $products = ProductResource::collection($product->limit(100000)->get());
        $data = [];
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $productTags = [];
            foreach ($product->tags as $tag){
                $productTags[] = $tag->id;
            }
            $product->tags = implode(",", $productTags);

            $data[] = $product;
        }

        return collect($data);
    }
}
```

Хотел сделать через chunk но там тупо идет загрузка без остановки (люди пишут так нельзя https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033142/15331960 )
Как посоветуете разделить или может есть какой то способ другой?

Comment: Как пишут `chunk()` использует `LIMIT` для запроса, который перебирает записи пока не пролистает нужное количство. При больших массивах данных, это может быть долго. Есть еще `chunkById()`, здесь чуть другой подход... выбирается срез по первичному ключу через `WHERE`, что работает быстрее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перешел на FastExcel. Советую. Там работает chunk при импорте и экспорте

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял в офф документация написано FromQuery https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html

Используется для большой даты.
Нужно просто убедиться что в конце нет ->get() и т.д. и т.п..
Пример:

```
return Invoice::query();

return Invoice::query()->whereYear('created_at', 2022);
```

У меня в базе 230 000 продуктов, пример сверху справился с задачей за 2 часа.
При этом нагрузка была меньше на 20% чем ->get() + без сбоя операции*

- Обычно если ->get()'ом получать оно в какой то момент может остановиться с причиной 'timed out' или без.
  А FromQuery:

> The Query passed with the FromQuery will automatically be chunked and
> each chunk will be appended to the Sheet. The chunking is done to
> limit the amount of Eloquent object it needs to keep in memory. It
> greatly reduces memory usage.

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/#processing-the-sheets

Из минусов нельзя использовать limit